# how to make httpclient portable on different handset such as android and j2me

Tags: android, java-me, httpclient

how to make httpclient portable on different handset such as android and j2me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that's not possible, since sending and receiving of HTTP requests is highly platform specific. Check out [Android HTML package documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html) and as comparison a [J2ME example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/HttpConnection.htm).

Comment: Thanks.I see the different. I think that both android j2me can connect to internet,so maybe there is some lib that impl httpclient on j2me...